# Scraping /Automated data collection with R Selenium: Dropdown confusion

Tags: r, facebook, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to automate data collection off the [Facebook Audience insights tool.](https://www.facebook.com/ads/audience_insights/people?act=71238683&age=18-&country=US)

I am having trouble in selecting different States.

```
loc<-mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "._5d5u ._58al")  
loc$sendKeysToElement(list(state.name[1]))
mybrowser$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key="enter"))
```

This will work only on certain occasions, but not all, as the drop down menu selecting the state won't pop up on every occasion.

You can easily replicate this by sending the state name to the element, manually deleting it and sending it again.

My questions are:

How can I solve this?
Why doesn't the dropdown appear when I send the keys to the element (even if I do so one by one) but it always does when I type?